# C: what is a void* besides a pointer?

Tags: c

Reading [CMU's OS Course Home Page](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E410/), they say:
"It is a good idea to be familiar with C conventions. For example, it is not generally the case that a void * is a pointer. If seeing a void * parameter, or a void ** parameter, in a function prototype would be confusing, this would be a good area to look into."

I honestly have no idea what they mean by this, what is a `void *` if not a pointer?

Comment: I can only think of a case when you want to fastly return a value from a thread created by `pthread_create`.

Comment: While the phrasing is a bit odd, my interpretation of their point is that a value of type `void *` is devoid of any meaning. When a function signature expects or returns such a value, you can only really understand the intent by reading the documentation, or the implementation.

Comment: Quote from their site: "This course is usually full". Looks like they expect people to see some obscure requirement, get scared and walk away.

Comment: I would say: a value of type `void *` is *usually* a pointer.  But it is an untyped pointer, so it can't be used as-is.  Before using it as a pointer, you have to cast it to the "correct" typed pointer, where "correct" means, "the type that you somehow know is correct for the actual pointed-to data".  But the only time a value of type `void *` is *not* a pointer is when someone is playing the game described in anatolyg's answer.  That trick, although popular in some circles, is viewed as bad style or an ugly hack in others. (anatolyg calls is "sloppy", and I agree.)

Comment: What a mealy-mouthed list item. The "Staff" link on that site isn't populated. Who're the teaching staff this upcoming semester? This is my alma mater and I need to tell them to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One case where `void *` is not a pointer involves passing data to a callback function. Imagine some library gives you a function which does some useful work, and calls your function (callback) in the middle of that work.

```
// useful_header.h
int do_useful_work(int data1, int data2, int (*callback)());
```

You call this function like this:

```
// your_code.c
int my_callback()
{
    ...
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    int useful_result = do_useful_work(2, 3, my_callback);
}
```

What if you want to pass data to your callback? The company which provides `do_useful_work` doesn't know which data your callback wants to get. So it provides the most generic thing - `void *`. Your callback interprets it as a pointer to your `struct`.

```
// useful_header.h
int do_useful_work(int data1, int data2, int (*callback)(void *), void *user_data);

// your_code.c
struct MyData
{
    int x, y, z;
};

int my_callback(void *pointer)
{
    struct MyData *data = pointer;
    ...
    return data->x + data->y + data->z + 42;
}

int main()
{
    struct MyData data = {5, 6, 7};
    int useful_result = do_useful_work(2, 3, my_callback, &data);
}
```

This has an edge-case: what if your callback wants to receive only a small item (of type `int`), and not a whole `struct`? Then you could interpret the pointer as `int`.

```
// your_code.c
int my_callback(void *not_really_pointer)
{
    int data = (int)not_really_pointer;
    ...
    return data + 42;
}

int main()
{
    int useful_result = do_useful_work(2, 3, my_callback, (void *)5);
}
```

Here, the `void *` argument is not really a pointer - it's a number, which is passed using `void *` type because C enforces type-checking.

Having said that, this is an example of sloppy coding; making a `struct` with one element would be clearer here.